# Can't access scheduled jobs page in Confluence Admin

Tags: confluence

Hi there is a backup task running for my confluence instance and there is a to do task on the front page of my admin account telling me to remove the (default) backup task from production.

But when I click on the link to configure Scheduled Jobs, instead of giving me a Page not found page, it gave me a Cannot display page in IE as if the connection is lost.

The link to the erroneous page is ../admin/scheduledjobs/viewscheduledjobs.action

Version is 4.3.3, please help.

Comment: Are any other admin pages not loading? 
Have you tried restarting the JVM / server?
Has anything changed recently?

Comment: Others are working correctly. Tried restarting, same. We upgraded from JRE6 to JRE7 recently. Still the same Tomcat6 server before and now.